# Время жизни переменной

Tags: c++, неопределённое-поведение

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int& in()
{
    int a = 2;
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << in();
    return 0;
}
```

В выводе я получаю `2`. Но разве не должно быть неопределённого поведения? Ведь переменная `a` локальная, а после выполнения функции уничтожиться? И возвращается ссылка на переменную.

Comment: Вы правы, действительно возникает Undefined Behavior.

Comment: Одно из нехороших свойств языка C++: если программа выдаёт верные результаты, то это не значит, что она написана верно))

Answer (score 6):

Ну тут действительно возникает UB, но то что у вас выводится 2, не значит, что его нет. UB означает, что в ситуации в которой он возник, компилятор может повести себя как угодно (например, вывести 2). Хотя мне интересно, в каком это у вас компиляторе безобидно вывелась 2. Обычно должно выскакивать предупреждение `-wreturn-local-addr`.

Answer (score 6):

Неопределенное поведение — оно такое неопределенное....

Понимаете, вы можете перебегать дорогу на красный свет светофора. Можете переходить ее с завязанными глазами и заткнутыми ушами. И у вас это будет отлично получаться... до поры до времени.

И то, что после нескольких переходов вы остались живы и здоровы (и даже не оштрафованы) — является ли основанием говорить, что "на красный переходить можно, я проверял!"?